# The getter 'clientSnapshot' isn't defined for the class

Tags: flutter, dart

In the code below, I retrieve trxn data from the Firebase document. One of the data elements in the trxn data is clientId. I need this to get the client data.

The first code snippet is where I get the trxn data. This code works fine.

```
_trxnStream = _db
            .collection('company')
            .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId)
            .collection('trxns')
            .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentTrxnId)
            .snapshots()
            .listen((trxnSnapshot) {
          clientTypeController.text = trxnSnapshot.data()?['clientType'] ?? "";
          _clientType = trxnSnapshot.data()?['clientType'] ?? "";

          _clientId = trxnSnapshot.data()?['clientId'] ?? "";
```

The second code snippet below is where I get the client data. The code occurs immediately after the _clientId is populated so it is executed immediately after the trxn data retrieval.

```
 try {
    _clientStream = _db
        .collection('client')
        .doc(_clientId)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((clientSnapshot) {
      clientFNameController.text =
          clientSnapshot.data()?['clientFName'] ?? "";
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
```

With this code, execution goes through creating the _clientStream but when it gets to populating the clientFNameController.text, it skips this line and exits the method. There is no error thrown but while debugging I add a watch for clientSnapshot and when I hover over the watch I get the following error.

```
error: org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: The getter 'clientSnapshot' isn't defined for the class '_TransactionDetailScreenState'.
 - '_TransactionDetailScreenState' is from 'package:deal_diligence/screens/transaction_detail_screen.dart' ('lib/screens/transaction_detail_screen.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'clientSnapshot'.
clientSnapshot.data()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0      DartDebugAdapter.evaluateRequest (package:dds/src/dap/adapters/dart.dart:1064:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      BaseDebugAdapter.handle (package:dds/src/dap/base_debug_adapter.dart:141:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I don't know why I am not getting any data retrieved from the client document. It does exist and I am getting the correct clientId from the trxn document.

Please help!
Thanks